# Smooth Structure of the Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Consider the torus $T^2=S^1\times S^1$(where $S^1$ is the unit circle
>   centered at $0$ in $\mathbb C$).
>
> - Define a smooth structure on $S^1$ and $T^2$.  ($\checkmark$)
> - Let $f:T^2 \rightarrow S^1$ be defined as $f(z,w)=zw$. Compute the rank of $f$ at each point. ($\checkmark$)
> - Let $N=f^{-1}(1)$. Is $N$ a submanifold of $T^2$? Describe $N$. (**?**)
> - Consider $g:S^1 \rightarrow T^2$ defined as $g(z)=(z,z)$. Is this function an immersion? Is the image an immersed submanifold,
>     embedding, regular submanifold? (**?**)

Despite "knowing" all the definitions of the question, I am not used to solve such differential geometry questions. I have very few thoughts on it but exactly need help. Any hints, "more than hint"s or solutions will surely be appreciated.

---

**Edit**: I more or less did the first part by writing out their charts etc. and the second part by finding out coordinate functions and this way formulating $f$ and then computing its rank. However, I still lack for some help to understand the latter two (submanifold issues) clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint for the third part: By the Regular Value Theorem, all you need to show is that $1$ is a regular value of $f$.

A hint for the fourth part: Remember that $g$ is an immersion iff its derivative is 1-1 at every point, i.e. iff the rank of $g$ is always $1=\dim{S^1}$.

Comment: Allright... This looks pretty helpful as I have just met the The Regular Value Theorem. Moreover, your hint on the fourth part will probably be totally comprehensible for me. I, by myself, am going to try to write exact solutions of these with your hints. If it will be ok, I will tick your answer. Appreciated...